# Is it possible to center elements using padding: 0 auto?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to center elements like I would do it with margins but with padding?

```
.elem{
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

would turn into:

```
.elem{
  padding: 0 auto;
}
```

I can see it doesn't work this way, but is there a way to simulate the same behaviour?

Comment: Please specify why you need/want to do it with padding. Show an example maybe on fiddle?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually you can't do padding: 0 auto; but there is a trick that would do the same:

```
.elem{
    padding: 0 calc(50% - 160px);
}
```

This is kind of similar to `max-width: 320px;` + `margin: 0 auto;`
So, unfortunatly, the max width is implicit but... this is really usefull anyway.

### The explanation:

This is what is really happening here:

```
paddingRight = paddingLeft = (parentWidth - elemMaxWidth) / 2;
```

Which means that we take the parent width, substract the element width, the rest is the value of the right padding plus the left padding, so we divide it by 2.

This method works on almost every browser, but old IE versions.